# How to Calculate the Probability (P(x)) in a Probability Distribution

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

I am working on statistics, and I am wondering how they got the values for the probability of having x number of girls in 4 births? I thought I understood this when reading the textbook, but even after going over it again, I am not too sure I understand it clearly. The way I understood P(x) to mean is that we can calculate the probability of a [discrete] random variable (in this case, the number of girls born out of four births). Although I know we can take the probability of an event happening to the nth value, I am not overly sure how they got the .063 on either side of the table below. From my understanding, wouldn't P(x) be .125 for both 0 girls and 4 girls?

| x | P(x) |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | .063 |
| 1 | .250 |
| 2 | .375 |
| 3 | .250 |
| 4 | .063 |

Any help is appreciated! Thank you

Comment: It will help if you provide more context,

Comment: It would be nice if you would summarize what you (thought you) understood from the textbook. Please click "Edit" above, rather than elaborating inside the comment section. Welcome to Math Stack.

Comment: They used the binomial distribution. But if they already give you the data, don't worry where it comes from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are using classic probability model for the problem. If $\Omega$ is the set of all possible vectors of 4 births, the $\Omega=\{(b_1,b_2,b_3,b_4): b_i\in\{girl, boy\}\}$, so there are $2^4=16$ possible results for 4 births, out of wich only $(boy,boy,boy,boy)$ corresponds to $x=0$, then $p(0)=1/16 =0.625$

A similar reasoning is used to compute the probability $p(x)$ of any $x$.

Comment: Thank you very much !